# Best position for Facebook Like button

Tags: facebook

What's the best position for a Facebook Like button, at the top of the page, or at the end of the text/content/module?

Which position has more visibility and is more effective?

Comment: Note: User Interface/User Experience (UI/UX) questions will get the most attention at [UX StackExchange Beta](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say next to your headline because if it's catchy people would like to share it instantly. I agree you may want to go down the route of user testing.

Answer (score 4):

Why not do some [A/B Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) and see where it works best for you? You can use [Google Analytics and Website Optimizer to do this](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=55589) for free.

Answer (score 1):

The best position is on your Facebook page, not your website. Those Facebook like icons slow down your page load time too much to be worth it. [Information Architects put out a great article about this](http://informationarchitects.net/blog/sweep-the-sleaze/).

Comment: Nice argument, +1. But I am one of those guys that are too lazy to copy&paste the url in my timeline, so I *feel* that the buttons must remain